# Some part of a function doesn't work in keypress eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a problem with not working part of a JavaScript code under some specific conditions. I have a task to do some simple credit card validation. If a card number starts with a specific number I need to show a specific card icon like Visa or Mastercard. At the start 3 of them are shown and as I'm typing card number 2 of them should disappear and if the number has the correct length for that specific card type the remaining one should turn green. The problem is when I try putting it in the eventListener for keypress nothing happens but when I try putting it outside the function everything works. For example:

```
cardNumber.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
    if(cardNumber.value.startsWith("4")){
        cards[0].style.color = "green"
    }
})
```

This doesn't work, the card doesn't turn green when I'm typing number 4 but if I try to just console log something when I type number 4 then it's shown in the console, so the event listener works but for some strange reason the styling doesn't. But if I just try doing

```
cards[0].style.color = "green"
```

outside of the function just to see if I'm doing then the icon turns green normally.

JavaScript:

```js
const cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
const cards = document.querySelectorAll("i");

cardNumber.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
    if(cardNumber.value.startsWith("4")){
        cards[0].style.color = "green"
        console.log("YES");
    }
})
```

HTML:

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="card mt-4">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cardNumber">Credit card number</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text text-muted" style="font-size: 1.5rem" id="type">
                <i class="fab fa-cc-visa mx-1" id="visa-icon"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-cc-amex mx-1" id="amex-icon"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard mx-1" id="mastercard-icon"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I can't change anything in the HTML - it's a JavaScript task.

Edit: Moving the constant variables containing card icons inside the eventListener worked.

Comment: Try using the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of keypress.

Comment: doesn't work either but thanks, i didn't know that event existed

Comment: I converted the code to a runnable snippet but that worked. So, I removed it it doesn't reproduce the problem and just left the code. I suspect the problem is when that JavaScript code is executed - it's likely before the flags are added, so perhaps the `cards` variable doesn't hold the information you expect. So, you should probably delay that code or use event delegation. Although, you can likely just move `const cards = document.querySelectorAll("i");` inside the event listener. It's a bit hard to guess without knowing how and where the JS is executed.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, moving it inside the eventListener worked just fine for me. Big thanks.

Comment: Why would moving card constant inside of the eventListener will make this to work? card constant was already in the scope of the eventListener. Are you sure you have not changed something else on top? I have reproduced your change and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try waiting till page is fully loaded, or inserting your code below the elements you wish to modify. DOM state could be messing with you.

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('Code can go here');
};
```

Comment: I don't know if i'm doing it right but if I do then this doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: You can try executing your code in console after page has loaded if it works then it's a load-state.

Comment: Make sure those variables you've defined too are not logging undefined, selection is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event you listen to input.

cardNumber.addEventListener("input", function(){

The problem with keypress is that the input is modified just after the event is triggered.

```js
    const cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll("i");

    cardNumber.addEventListener("input", function(e){
        if(cardNumber.value.startsWith("4")){
            cards[0].style.color = "green"
        }
    })
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <main class="container">
      <div class="card mt-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cardNumber">Credit card number</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text text-muted" style="font-size: 1.5rem" id="type">
                    <i class="fab fa-cc-visa mx-1" id="visa-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-cc-amex mx-1" id="amex-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard mx-1" id="mastercard-icon"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: @Aleksander Was useful my answer? Remember to mark the right answer, so we can all learn and help other people with the same problem.